# JavaScript Gallery to SPservices

Tags: javascript, spservices

I found nice JavaScript Gallery [here](http://js-tutorial.com/fotorama-a-simple-stunning-powerful-jquery-gallery-759). I was trying to get data from Sharepoint library using SPServices. But Didn't work. Is there any issue with My code?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Jscript/Jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Jscript/SPServices/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Script/js/fotorama.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Script/js/fotorama.css" />


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "2007PhotoAlbum",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
   
  
        var liHtml = "<div class='fotorama'><img src='" + "/photos/2007PhotoAlbum/" + $(this).attr("ows_PicFilename") +"'" + "></div>";
        $("#fotorama").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});


</script>
<div id="fotorama" data-width="700" data-ratio="700/467" data-max-width="100%"></div>
<script>
$('.fotorama').fotorama({
  width: 700,
  maxwidth: '100%',
  ratio: 16/9,
  allowfullscreen: true,
  nav: 'thumbs'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SPServices call may not be complete before the gallery code is run. This makes it look like SPServices is returning no data. You could start by checking that SPServices is returning data. This code will write the output to the page.

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "2007PhotoAlbum",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        /***********************************Debugging*******************************/
            var out = $().SPServices.SPDebugXMLHttpResult({
            node: xData.responseXML
            });
            $("#debug").html("").append("<b>This is the output from the GetList operation:</b>" + out);
        /***************************************************************************/

      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {


        var liHtml = "<div class='fotorama'><img src='" + "/photos/2007PhotoAlbum/" + $(this).attr("ows_PicFilename") +"'" + "></div>";
        $("#fotorama").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
```

As long as this returns data, I recommend rewriting your SPServices call using promises. Then run `.fotorama` after the promise is returned. Marc compares with and without promises [here](http://sympmarc.com/2013/05/01/comparing-spservices-2013-01-calls-with-async-vs-promises-methods/).